# installing packages in R - warning messages

Tags: r

I tried to install packages in R. But, R software gives warning messages in the below picture. How to install packages in ?

[image]

Comment: Are the warnings that big of a deal? Can you post a screenshot of them?

Comment: I posted it above. dear @InfiniteFlashChess

Comment: When downloading the link in warning messages, I cannot install it as well. @InfiniteFlashChess

Comment: where are the warnings?

Comment: dear @B11b: show us the warnings

Comment: The red writing... Now, did I successfully install this packages? Sorry, I tried to learn using R software by myself:( Is there no problem to install it? dear @rawr

Comment: @cory The red writing... Now, did I successfully install this packages? Sorry, I tried to learn using R software by myself:( Is there no problem to install it?

Comment: Looks fine. Did you try to use it?

Comment: Looks like the installation was successful. The red text isn't a real warning. try:
library(bujar) and then ?bujar .
If you get to the helping page, your package is sucessfully installed.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like a 'warning,' necessarily.  It's just telling you that it downloaded that file and where the file was placed on your computer.

Did you try:  `library(bujar)` ?

Comment: I tried library (bujar), but not work. Yes, I download that file on my computer. Well, How to install that file? Can you show me a way. Thank you

Comment: The general method for installing R packages is to type in R:  `install.packages("bujar")` wait for everything to download and then `library(bujar)`.  As @maRtin mentioned, after running that, try `?bujar` and if it installed correctly it will open the help doc.  Did you get an error or message after trying that?

Comment: Firstly, I used the command: install.packages("bujar"). And I got the same message. Then, I continue to use the command library(bujar). Then, I run ?bujar , help doc open correctly. I didn't get any error or message. Thank you dear @Bird :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your internet connections and make sure that this packages whether or not available in your R version..